# ^ operator in java

Tags: java, operators

Can anyone explain the use of ^ operator in java with some examples?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

This is the same as ^ in most languages, just an XOR.

```
false ^ false == false
true ^ false == true
false ^ true == true
true ^ true == false
```

Comment: Well, not _any_ language - VB uses ^ for exponentiation.

Comment: Yes but VB always uses different stuff anyway... ;)

Comment: Lua also uses ^ for exponentiation.

Comment: BTW: It could be repleced by simple `a != b`

Answer (score 9):

Some of the other answers only say it is a bitwise XOR, but note that it can also be a logical XOR if the operands are of boolean type, according to [this source](http://java.operator-precedence.com/).

Answer (score 6):

It's bitwise XOR.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Answer (score 4):

That's the **bitwise exclusive OR operation**.
Check out the [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators section](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) of the [Java tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

In java ^ operator used for bitwise XOR operation.

Follow this link to see the operator precedence also.

http://www.uni-bonn.de/~manfear/javaoperators.php

Comment: The link is broken. Could you edit the answer with a new link?