# Logical expressions in java

Tags: java

So on Java , an "AND" statement is &&, "OR" statement is ||...

What about for XOR then... that is if I have two choices. I HAVE to pick one, but I can't pick both.

HOWEVER,

```
private class CheckBoxListener implements ItemListener{
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
    if(one.isSelected()^two.isSelected()){

    thehandler handler = new thehandler();
    button.addActionListener(handler);

        }   

 }}
```

Even if I have both checkboxes selected, the button is 'enabled'. This is the handler for the button fyi:

```
private class thehandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

    dispose();
}
```

So if both are selected, and If i click the button. the frame should not dispose. It should only dispose when either one of them is selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` is the XOR operator in Java.

---

Regarding your Swing problem, the problem is that you are not inspecting the state of the checkboxes when the button is clicked, but rather when the checkboxes are selected. You should instead have something like this:

```
private class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {

    /*
     * You will probably define a constructor that accepts the two checkboxes
     * as arguments.
     */

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (one.isSelected() ^ two.isSelected()) {
            dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The alternative approach is to create one instance of the `ActionListener`. You would add it with `addActionListener` when exactly one of the checkboxes is checked, and remove it with `removeActionListener` otherwise:

```
private class CheckBoxListener implements ItemListener {

    private ActionListener buttonActionListener = new thehandler();

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        if(one.isSelected() ^ two.isSelected()) {
            button.addActionListener(buttonActionListener);
        } else {
            button.removeActionListener(buttonActionListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that's the **bitwise** XOR, not a logical one.

Comment: It's both bitwise and logical. See [section 15.22](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.22) of the Java language specification.

Comment: Neat, I never knew you could use `^` on booleans in Java.

Comment: Me too, I didn't know you could use it for both. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my question. The code is still not complying with the ^ or !=

Comment: @razshan: you need to check the state of the checkboxes when the button is clicked, not when the checkboxes are checked

Comment: @ide, thanks. even then its not working. I used the second option

Comment: For booleans, `^` is in fact equivalent to `!=` (apart from the difference in priority)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `!=` operator. For two booleans it has the same truth table as an "actual" XOR operator.

Comment: You seem to indicate that `^` wouldn't work for boolean expressions.

Comment: @aioobe: I removed that part. I had no idea it could be used with booleans as well.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in other answers, the xor operator for boolean (and bitwise) expressions is `^`.

```
boolean a = true;
boolean b = false;

boolean c = a ^ b;  // c == true
```

(It should also be noted that `&` and `|` works just fine for boolean expressions too.)

---

**So, why does `&&` and `||` exist, but not `^^`?**

The explanation is evident if you consider the difference between `&` and `&&`.

The first one (`&`) does not [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) the evaluation, while `&&` does. So logically, `^^` would correspond to the short circuited version of `^`. But, there is no way `^` can be short-circuited (no matter what the first operand evaluates to, the second operand needs to be evaluated) so `^^` would be completely redundant.

Answer (score 2):

`^` is the boolean logical exclusive OR

Comment: @SLaks: its called a "boolean logical" XOR numerous times... For booleans its the XOR. So while it is bitwise, the 'no' is a bit quick, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

All of Java's operators, including XOR.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 1):

Way to go

```
boolean xor = a ^ b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the long way. This is a logical XOR.

`!(p && q) && (p || q)`

Answer (score 0):

You use the ^ character.

See [Creating a "logical exclusive or" operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726652/creating-a-logical-exclusive-or-operator-in-java)