# Exclusive OR Java code

Tags: java, boolean, operators, xor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a “logical exclusive or” operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726652/creating-a-logical-exclusive-or-operator-in-java)

I'm struggling with trying to write Java code for an exclusive or operator.

I have 1 method called `leftTurn()`

```
leftTurn(a,b,c) XOR leftTurn(a,b,d)
```

&

```
leftTurn(c,d,a) XOR leftTurn(c,d,b)
```

I dont know how to construct Java code for this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726652/creating-a-logical-exclusive-or-operator-in-java

Comment: Can't you use the regular '^' XOR operator?

Answer (score 5):

The Java XOR operator is `^`.

So:

```
leftTurn(a,b,c) ^ leftTurn(a,b,d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming leftTurn return int

```
leftTurn(a,b,c) ^ leftTurn(a,b,d) 
leftTurn(c,d,a) ^ leftTurn(c,d,b)
```

Answer (score 2):

If `^` is a bit obscure for you, you can just use `!=` which does the same thing for booleans.

```
boolean oneTurn = leftTurn(a,b,c) != leftTurn(a,b,d);
```

If you need bitwise XOR, you need `^`