# Need explanation of one Java If-Else logic

Tags: java, if-statement

I need explanation of the below code execution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long tail = 2000L;
    Long distance = 1999L;
    Long story = 1000L;
    if ((tail > distance) ^ ((story * 2) == tail))
        System.out.println("a");
    if ((distance + 1 != tail) ^ ((story * 2) == distance))
        System.out.println("2");

}
```

After the code execution no output is produced.

Comment: What output would you expect if both conditions were false?

Comment: Exactly which part of this code don't you understand?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Comment: Remember that the ^ operator can be thought of as __this or that, but not both__.

Comment: I was unaware of the ^ operator :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^` stands for [XOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726652/creating-a-logical-exclusive-or-operator-in-java) operation of 2 booleans, in below statement

```
if ((tail > distance) ^ ((story * 2) == tail))
```

`(tail > distance)` is **true**

`((story * 2) == tail`) is **true**

and `true XOR true` is `false`

Answer (score 3):

the XOR output table looks like this:
X Y Output
0 0 0
1 0 1
0 1 1
1 1 0

So based on both your booleans being true you will get a false return from the if statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long tail = 2000L;
    Long distance = 1999L;
    Long story = 1000L;
    if ((tail > distance) ^ ((story * 2) == tail))
        System.out.println("a");
    if ((distance + 1 != tail) ^ ((story * 2) == distance))
        System.out.println("2");
}

if (((tail > distance) ^ ((story * 2) == tail)) == true)
            System.out.println("a");
```

is equal to:

```
if (((2000 > 1999) ^ ((1000 * 2) == 2000)) == true)
            System.out.println("a");
```

is equal to:

```
if ((true ^ true) == true)
            System.out.println("a");
```

is equal to:

```
if (false == true)
            System.out.println("a");
```

and therefor it's never printed.

Similar reasoning applies to the second `if-else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Both your conditions are `false` thats why you have no output

Answer (score 0):

You never have anything returned as there isn't anything to return - both conditions are false.

Also I'm fairly sure it should be written as

```
if ((tail > distance) ^ ((story * 2) == tail)) {
    System.out.println("a");
}
if ((distance + 1 != tail) ^ ((story * 2) == distance)) {
    System.out.println("2");
}
```

You could also test it by saying

```
if ((tail > distance) ^ ((story * 2) == tail)) {
    System.out.println("a");
} else {
    System.out.println("Condition 1 False");
}
if ((distance + 1 != tail) ^ ((story * 2) == distance)) {
    System.out.println("2");
} else {
    System.out.println("condition 2 False");
}
```

Alternatively, did you mean to write

```
if ((tail > distance) || ((story * 2) == tail)) {
    System.out.println("a");
}
if ((distance + 1 != tail) || ((story * 2) == distance)) {
    System.out.println("2");
}
```

Using the logical OR instead?

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a basic understanding of the difference between 'or' and 'exclusive-or'. The exclusive-or condition a ^ b is true only if (a is true and b is false) OR (a is false and b is true).

Answer (score 0):

^ is XOR. Which is almost the opposite of OR.

OR:

```
True True = True
True False = False
False True = False
False False = False
```

XOR:

```
True True = False
True False = True
False True = True 
False False = False
```

Comment: I know, I know, true and false are low case in Java.