# Cipher Block Chaining: XOR implementation in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, xor, cbc-mode

How you implement the XOR from CBC (Cipher Block Chaining) in Java? 
I know how to do it when both of my values are booleans, but what do I do if I have numbers instead of booleans?

For Example:

```
i1 = 15
i2 = 4
```

How do I `XOR` i1 and i2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a "logical exclusive or" operator in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726652/creating-a-logical-exclusive-or-operator-in-java)

Comment: yeah but I dont want to XOR booleans. I want to XOR numbers :D

Comment: It works on boolean and integral types.

Comment: So, whats wrong with using `i1 ^ i2 ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has a bitwise XOR operator build in, see the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1). The XOR works on all primitive integral types (i.e. types that directly represent numbers for you and me): `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long` and `char`. This XOR operator will do a bitwise XOR of the bits at identical positions, and then output the result. There is also the `^=` which will store the result back in the left hand variable.

Now it depends on your implementation of CBC if you would do this on bytes or on 32 bit integers (`int`). Normally you would use bytes, but if you've implemented AES using 32 bit constructs you would use integers. Integers would be slightly faster, but the time that XOR takes will pale in comparison with the block cipher operation anyway.

So you can simply have a `for` loop (up to the block size in bytes) and XOR each and every byte of the last ciphertext with the next plaintext during encryption or the last ciphertext with the result - after decryption - of the next ciphertext during decryption.

---

You may need to cast back to a byte when using the XOR operation on two byte values, as Java automatically upcasts the operands - and therefore the result - to 32 bit integers (`int`):

```
byte x = 0b0011; // 0b indicates a binary literal
byte y = 0b0101; 
byte r = (byte) (x ^ y); // results in 0b0110 or the value 6 in decimals
```

---

Bytes are signed values in Java, meaning that you may get negative values. That's OK though, you can simply ignore this as long as you just use bitwise operations. It's only of importance during mathematical operations such as addition or multiplication.

Comment: Thanks go to [Ammar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43792996/589259) for indicating that you need to downcast back to bytes or shorts again.

Answer (score 1):

using `short` integers :

```
short s1 = ...
short s2 = ...
short result = (short) (s1 ^ s2);
```

This is the most efficient way to XOR two shorts together. It does not run into the overhead of creating BigIntegers and the cast will never cause an overflow issue as both s1 and s2 are shorts to begin with.

Comment: There is however absolutely no reason to use shorts.