# Java recursion odd of sum

Tags: java, recursion

We have to find sum of array and then return if the value is odd (boolean) using recursion

```
A = {87, 31, 15, 25, 10, 15, 21, 75)
methodname(A, pos) //position is 0 at the begining
```

i did this so far, but i'm way off since i can't sum and return boolean in the same line

```
if (pos == array.length-1) {
    return A[pos] % 2 != 0
} else {
    if (pos < A.length - 1)
        return A[pos] + methodname(A, pos + 1) % 2 == 1;
}
```

Comment: I think you need a loop, what is methodname?

Comment: @Rab: he's supposed to use recursion (in place of a loop), but he does not post a complete method, making the question very difficult to answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels oh alright, Didn't really look at the title. I thought it would be something else because his returning in both statements

Comment: Please show how you are calling this code

Comment: int[] A = {1,5,7,8};
         System.out.println(Rec(A, 0));                 //0 is the position

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isSumOdd(new int[]{3, 3, 4}, 0));
}

private static boolean isSumOdd(int[] arr, int pos) {
    return pos == arr.length - 1
            ? arr[pos] % 2 != 0
            : isSumOdd(arr, pos + 1) ^ arr[pos] % 2 != 0; //Sum of 2 numbers can be odd iff exactly one of them is odd.
}
```

Comment: @Asrar Why not?

Comment: I see ? and : in the code. What is that for? am i missing something

Comment: @Asrar it's called ternary operator. This is equivalent to writing `if (pos == arr.length - 1) {
            return arr[pos] % 2 != 0;
        } else {
            return isSumOdd(arr, pos + 1) ^ arr[pos] % 2 != 0;
        }`

Comment: @Asrar *This solution is not even close* is a pretty rude comment to make when you do not even understand the code.  I think you should apologize to Kartlik who has gone to the trouble to help you.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I said "2 numbers", you gave example of 3 numbers :). Anyway, would you like me to remove that line? No apologies needed, non-native speakers can sometimes sound rude while they don't actually mean it (me being one of them).

Comment: My bad if i said something wrong. But i never came across ^ in java yet. May be i have to learn a lot yet

Comment: Moved that line to the right place to avoid confusion. @Asrar ^ is [XOR operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/726665/1039555).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following approach (syntax might be wrong, treat the following as pseudo code):

```
  // gives whether the sum from i to end 
  // is even or odd 
  Boolean sumIsEven(int[] arr, int i ){

      //base case
      if(arr.length-1==i){
           return arr[i]%2 ==0;
      }

      if(arr[i]%2 == 0){
           return sumIsEven(arr, i +1);
      }else{
           // arr[i] is odd
           return !sumIsEven(arr, i +1);
      }
}
```

But this will give only if the whole sum is odd/even

Comment: Why do you have int return type. I want to first sum all the numbers in the array and then return a boolean if that is odd or not.

Comment: Sorry return type should be boolean... will fix that