# Date Validation in Java fails

Tags: java, javafx

I'm totally new to Java programming and I'm trying to create a Java FX project. I've followed tutorials about the date validation method but it seems to fail.In this certain part I have to make a list with objects inserted by a user in text fields. That includes a date but it needs to be valid.

Below in this piece of code, the object I need to get validated is **datep** . I've created a method in which if the string is valid, it should set my flag to true and return it. Before the list is created I inserted an **if** statement to check whether that my **flag** is set to true which means that the date is verified according to the format.When I run it,it creates the list whatsoever even if the date is invalid.Am I putting the if statement in the wrong part? Cause I think the method is fine.

```java
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == NewrentBtn) {
    
    String vehiclen =OximaTxT.getText();
    String clientn = ClientTxT.getText();
    String store = StoreTxT.getText();
    String storer = StorerTxT.getText();
    String timerp = TimeTxT.getText();
    String timer = TimerTxT.getText();
    String datep = DateTxT.getText(); // <-------------
    String dater = DaterTxT.getText();
    Integer sum = Integer.parseInt(SumTxT.getText());    
    if(flag = true) { // <------------
        createRental(id, vehiclen, store, datep, timerp, clientn, storer, dater, timer, sum);
        clearTextFields();
    }
}

public boolean Checkdate(String datep) { // <-------------
    
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date BOD = null;
    df.setLenient(false);
    
    try
    {
        BOD = df.parse(datep); // <----------------
        flag = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
}

public void createRental(int id,String vehiclen,String store,String datep,String timerp,String clientn,String storer,String dater,String timer,int sum ) {
    Rental m = new Rental(id,vehiclen,store,datep,timerp,clientn,storer,dater,timer,sum);
    RentalList.add(m);
    rentalTableView.getItems().add(m);
            
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dean i was wondering where are you making the validation of the dateFormat? or in other words where do you call the `public boolean CheckDate(datep)` method before the ìf`validation in the `public void handle(MouseEvent event)` method.

Comment: Hey there.I see it's missing out from this piece but now that I updated it, I call the method right before the if statement

Comment: I posted a full solution, let me know if it works. If you need further help let me know and we find a way to tutor you a bit.

Comment: Oh damn of course..beside the method calling, I inserted a "=" and not "==" inside the if statement.Thanks a lot for helping me out Nicholas!I appreciate the advice as well, I'll take it upon note to have a cleaner structured code

Comment: java naming conventions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of what you are trying to achieve here is my suggestion to modify the code.

First of all let me explain to you two issues i found: the first one is that you are missing the call to the validation method of the Date, that is the call to the `CheckDate(datep)` when you receive the text input and store the flag variable, or so it seems as we dont have the full code (which is ok ); and second you are missing a `=`in the `if(flag = true)`, it should be `if(flag == true)`

So here is the full code:

```
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == NewrentBtn) {

        String vehiclen =OximaTxT.getText();
        String clientn = ClientTxT.getText();
        String store = StoreTxT.getText();
        String storer = StorerTxT.getText();
        String timerp = TimeTxT.getText();
        String timer = TimerTxT.getText();
        String dater = DaterTxT.getText();
        Integer sum = Integer.parseInt(SumTxT.getText());
        String datep = DateTxT.getText();

        boolean flag = Checkdate(datep);
        if(flag == true) {
            createRental(id,vehiclen,store,datep,timerp,clientn,storer,dater,timer,sum);
            clearTextFields();
        }
    }
}
```

This way you are verifying if the date is correctly formatted and continue the process if it is according to your scheme.

Finally i have three recommendations as you are new to java programming:

1. For all methods the first letter should always be in lowercase like `public boolean checkDate()` this way you can differentiate a method from a Class, which will always start in Uppercase like `public class Product`. The only exception for this is the constructor of a class.
2. You should never mix the `graphical interface` logic, with the `logical processing` logic. This is: you should keep the processing part in one package and the graphic component in another and relate both of them by creating an instance of the `processing logic` in the `graphical interface`.
3. The user input validation should be directly made in the handler method with try-catch clauses like the following.

Here:

```
public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == NewrentBtn) {

        String vehiclen =OximaTxT.getText();
        String clientn = ClientTxT.getText();
        String store = StoreTxT.getText();
        String storer = StorerTxT.getText();
        String timerp = TimeTxT.getText();
        String timer = TimerTxT.getText();
        String dater = DaterTxT.getText();
        Integer sum = Integer.parseInt(SumTxT.getText());
        try {
            String datep = DateTxT.getText();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            df.parse(date);
            createRental(id,vehiclen,store,datep,timerp,clientn,storer,dater,timer,sum);
            clearTextFields();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            /* Here you handle what happens when if fails, you can create a JDialog to show
            the error or create an alert, whatever you need */
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And voila a cleaner version

Comment: Oh damn of course..beside the method calling, I inserted a "=" and not "==" inside the if statement.Thanks a lot for helping me out Nicholas!I appreciate the advice as well, I'll take it upon note to have a cleaner structured code

Comment: @Dean This is one of the reasons you should not test a boolean variable with a boolean literal. Simply use `if (flag)` instead of `if (flag == true)` and use `if (!flag)` instead of `if (flag == false)`. The versions with `==` are discouraged, at least in the Java community. That said, it's acceptable to compare two boolean _variables_ with `!=` (i.e. `if (flag1 != flag2)`) when appropriate; [that's one way to implement an XOR test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726652/creating-a-logical-exclusive-or-operator-in-java).

Comment: @Slaw is correct, I also do not use the bolean literals but for the sake of your understanding I posted the closest solution to what you already understand. And thank you Slaw for the advice