# Are booleans implicitly true?

Tags: java, boolean

I'm a bit confused on this bit of code.

My professor explained that the output will always be true but I'm confused on why.

I changed the boolean to both true and false but the output is always true and I'm having a hard time explaining the logic behind it. I assumed that since a false && true will always represent true, then the true and false cancels out like algebra? Apologies if I'm confusing you guys, I'm quite confused myself!

> ```
> public class TestProgram {
>
>     public static void main(String args[]) {
>         boolean answer = false;
>         boolean output = (answer && true) ^ !answer;
>         System.out.println("output = " + output);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: It doesn't matter what answer is, true XOR false == false XOR true == true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a "logical exclusive or" operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726652/creating-a-logical-exclusive-or-operator-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code for calculating `output` means:

```
(answer AND true) XOR (NOT answer)
```

Therefore, when `answer` is `true`:

```
(answer AND true) XOR (NOT answer)
 = (true AND true) XOR (NOT true)
 = true XOR false
 = true
```

And when `answer` is `false`:

```
(answer AND true) XOR (NOT answer)
 = (false AND true) XOR (NOT false)
 = false XOR true
 = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which part is confusing you but I will try to explain your code line by line:

1. `boolean answer = false; // answer is false or 0`
2. `boolean output = (answer && true) ^ !answer;`

   a. `(answer && true) = false or 0` because answer is 0. And returns true or 1 ONLY if all conditions (2 in this case) are true.

   b. `!answer = true` because the negation of answer (false or ) is true or 1.

   c. `^` is a bitwise exclusive or operator: meaning a bit by bit comparison between two parameters is performed. The result for a bit position is 1 if one or the other (but not both) of the corresponding bits in the operands is 1.

For example:

```
00110 ^  00011 = 00101
```

So in your case, you have: `false ^ true  = 0 ^ 1 = 1` (or true) because only one of the corresponding bits is 1.

NOTE that:

1. `true ^ true` = false
2. `true ^ false` = true
3. `false ^ true` = true
4. `false ^ false` = false