# groovy ^ operator

Tags: groovy, operators

When given two boolean arguments, the ^ operator performs exclusive or, e.g.

```
true ^ true == false
true ^ false == true
false ^ true == true
false ^ false == false
```

When given two numeric arguments, it does something, but I've no idea what. At first I thought it was modular division because

```
(5 ^ 5) == 0
```

However

```
(10 ^ 4) == 14
```

So it's not modular division, is it some kind of bit-shifting?

Comment: It's bitwise exclusive or, same as Java

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460542/operator-in-java

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`^` does the same thing as it does in Java and most other languages:

It's a bitwise exclusive OR (short: bitwise XOR)

This means that for every bit in the binary representation of the two numbers the resulting bit in the output will be the `bit_in_first_value ^ bit_in_second_value`.

Comment: Indeed, to my knowledge all langauges strongly derived from C have this prescribed behavior of their XOR operators. E.G. `perl -le 'print(10 ^ 4)'` prints out 14. Groovy and Perl occupy a similar ecological nice, so much so that [Groovy’s version](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_groovy/index.html) was the first out of dozens of languages whose translation of the *Perl Cookbook* is complete in the [PLEAC — Programming Language Examples Alike Cookbook](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/) repository on Sourceforge. OCaml was the second. Python is at 85% and Ruby at only 65%. Groovy is easy and fun.