# What does result = result + (char)(c ^ d) do?

Tags: java, int, operator-keyword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [^ operator in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460542/operator-in-java)

I was assuming that `c ^ d` is a calculation like 'the power of', so `c = 5`, `d = 2`, result is 25. I think I'm wrong, though.

Can you explain what `(c ^ d)` does in java, for example in

```
result = result + (char)(c ^ d)
```

Comment: ^ is a bitwise XOR. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460542/operator-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` is the bitwise xor meaning that `0b0101^0b0010` (5^2) is `0b0111` and `0b0101^0b0111` is `0b0010`

look at the truth table of xor (the result is 1 if the input are different

```
a b | a^b
---------
0 0 | 0
0 1 | 1
1 0 | 1
1 1 | 0
```

the bitwise operators take each bit of the terms and apply the operator to each bit

Answer (score 3):

The `^` operator performs a *Bitwise Exclusive OR.*

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

For raising a number to a power, you would use the [Math.pow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

That one is the bitwise XOR operator.

Answer (score 1):

[^ is a bitwise XOR.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460542/operator-in-java)