# What does ^ (caret) mean in Java

Tags: java, syntax

What does the `^` (caret) mean in Java syntax?  Why does `6^3` return `5`?

Comment: It's the lesser-used XOR operation.  1^0 = 1

See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460542/operator-in-java

Comment: Adel, you should create an answer.

Comment: @Hiro2k - I did! But some gremlin in the SO-code automatically made it a comment. I am bitter now :<

Comment: The same thing it means in every programming language?

Comment: @BrianRoach - Wait.. hmm, in python RegEXP it's the string start?

Comment: @Brain: It's exponentiation in Visual Basic... And superscript in LaTeX... And beginning of line/string (depending on mode) in regular expressions... And "start going upwards" in befunge... And I think it's even "logical and" in APL.

Comment: @Adel - A regex is not a programming language. It has the same meaning there in all languages as well. In this context, however, he clearly doesn't mean in a regex as shown in his question.

Comment: @BrianRoach - Gotcha, good point. Thank You So Much

Comment: @cha0site - Yet another reason not to consider VB a programming language :-D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's the bitwise XOR operator. XOR is exclusive or.

6 in binary (lets assume 4 bits) is `0110`, 3 in binary is `0011`.

So, we get:

```
0110
0011 XOR
----
0101
```

And `0101` is 5.

Comment: Its also the *boolean* XOR operator, also that is probably used less often.

Answer (score 2):

See [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).