# Pairs of Positive Integers with loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

(Btw we haven't used arrays yet. Im in my loop chapter)

I need to write a Java program that will output all pairs of positive integers, (a,b) such that a and b are greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 1000 and the ratio (a^2 + b^2 + 1) / (a*b) is an integer.

My way to go about it is make a nested loop

```
for (a = 0; a <= 1000; a++)
    for (b = 0; b <= 1000; b++)
    {
        //answer = a^2 + b^2 + 1 / (a*b)
        //if (answer % 1 == 0)
        //    System.out.println("(" + a + ", " + b + ")") 
    }
```

would that work properly or am i looking at this problem all wrong

Comment: You should use `if( (a*a + b*b + 1) % (a*b) == 0 )` to see if a²+b²+1 is divisible by ab. Using `%` right away works on all numeric types. Your current approach only works on floating-point types (`float` and `double`), because of integer division. Dividing an `int` by an `int` would result in an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is correct,

But one thing you make sure,

you are using the expression : `answer = a^2 + b^2 + 1 / (a*b)`

But you have mentioned in your question as `(a^2 + b^2 + 1) / (a*b)`.

So make sure that you are using those parenthesis, otherwise operator precedence may cause you some problem

Like `1 / (a*b)` will be solved after `(a*b)` is completed and you don't want it like that, right.  So take care of operator precedence or use parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Using nested loops would be an exhaustive search and is probably the most straight-forward approach to this problem. A couple of things to keep in mind:

1. The `^` operator is actually an [XOR operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460542/operator-in-java). Use Math.pow(a, 2) or `a * a` if you are looking to sqaure `a`
2. Beware of integer division
3. You probably want to start your loops at 1 instead of 0

Comment: i was summarizing thats why it was a comment and not code.
I HAVE to use that formula
I HAVE to start at 0 (greater than or EQUAL to)

Comment: Gotcha. I suggested not starting at 0 because you said _positive_ integers, and when diving by 0 (e.g. when a and b are both 0) your ratio will result in NaN or an exception (in the case of integer division)

Answer (score 0):

I can change your expression to following:

> 1. (a^2 + b^2 + 1+2ab-2ab) / (a*b)
> 2. ((a+b)^2-2ab)/(a*b)
> 3. (a+b)^2/ab -2

So equation is simple now you need to check that (a+b)^2/ab > 2. Ultimate check is that sum of 2 numbers should be divisible by their product.

Add a check for a=0 and b=0 as both are divisors.