# The operator ^ is undefined for arguments

Tags: java, math, operators

```
(((difference - previousStep)/1000)^2)
//difference and previousStep are both doubles
```

Why can't I use the ^ operator with doubles? I just want to know why. Luckily for me I can just multiple difference - previousStep by itself because i'm just squaring it, but if i need to bring it to the Nth power, then this would be a problem. So why can't you ^ doubles and is there a way around this?

Comment: The caret (^) operator is explained in another SO question [^ operator in java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460542/operator-in-java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `^` operator isn't the exponentiation operator in Java; [it's the bitwise XOR operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html), which doesn't make much sense with `double` arguments.

You can either multiply the value by itself or you can call [`Math.pow(yourValue, 2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) for exponentiation.

Answer (score 0):

There operator `^` is not used for exponents in Java, please use `Math.pow(((difference - previousStep)/1000), 2)` instead

Comment: There is a `^` operator. It's just not exponentiation.